# search through cell elements that contain a string, then delete it

Tags: matlab, cell

Hi I want to search a cell array for any elements containing the letter 'x'. I can delete a cell element by doing the following:

```
mycell(3) = []
```

but trying to search through the elements id the difficult part. I am using:

```
offending_cell  = strcmp('x', mycell);
```

however this is just picking out all elements regardless of x appearing in them. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
ind = (~cellfun('isempty',(regexp(mycell,'x'))));
```

This gives logical indices for cells that contain `'x'`. If you want to delete those cells:

```
mycell(ind) = [];
```

The problem with you apporach was that `strcmp` looks for *exact* matching, not if the string *contains* a given character.

Comment: Or why not `mycell(cellfun(@(x)(~isempty(regexp(x,'x'))),mycell))=[]` ?

Comment: @P0W That works too, but it is _slower_. `cellfun` works faster with "builtin" (quoted) functions such as `'isempty'` than with generic functions (`@...`). And it seems to take even more time with anonymous functions (`@(x)...`). That is, it would be best to define `func = @(x)(~isempty(regexp(x,'x')))` and then use `mycell(cellfun(func,mycell))=[]`, but that would still be slower than `mycell(~cellfun('isempty',(regexp(mycell,'x'))))=[]`